# Get Discord Bot to Check If It's Reacted To It's Own Post

Tags: discord, discord.js, google-translation-api

I'm writing a discord bot using discord.js, and I've recently added a //translate command that utilizes the Google Translate API to translate between all the languages supported by Google Translate. I want to add the ability to quickly re-translate the translation back into English using reactions, and I want the bot to check if 1 person has reacted to the post with the provided reaction, and if they have, re-translate the translation back to English.

I'm really close, but I've run into the problem that I can't get the bot to check if it itself sent the reaction, so it auto-retranslates back to English because it's detecting it's own reaction. I want for it to only re-translate when A PERSON reacts, and only ONCE.

I'm not super familiar with this area of discord.js yet, so I can't really figure out how to do it.

Here is the code:

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}translate`) || msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}t`)) {
        const text = args.slice(1).join(` `);
        if (!text) return msg.channel.send(`Nothing to translate provided! Languages codes are at https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages !\n Command syntax: \`${prefix}translate\` or \`${prefix}t\` [text] [language code]`);
        const text1 = text.substring(0, text.length - 2)
        const target = text.substring(text.length - 2, text.length) || languages
        translate
        .translate(text1, target)
        .then(results => {
            const translation = results[0];
            msg.channel.send(`Translation: ${translation}`).then(sentText => {
                sentText.react(``);
                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
                };
                sentText.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 2, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && sentText.react.me === false) {
                        const target = `en`
                        translate
                        .translate(text1, target)
                        .then(results => {
                        const translation = results[0];
                        msg.channel.send(`Translation: ${translation}`);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                        })
                    }   
                })
            })
        })
//code for command continues below this line, but it is irrelevant to what I'm trying to achieve
```

Expected result: Bot re-translates back to English if a user reacts with the provided reaction, and only once.

Actual result: Bot does nothing, or, if I remove the `&& sentText.react.me === false`, the bot re-translates back to English because it's detecting its own reaction.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In your filter, you can check to make sure the user isn't the client, like so...

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id !== client.user.id;
```

That way, only reactions that are *not* added by the client are collected.

You'll have to change your `max` option in the collector to 1, since the client's own reaction won't be collected. You can also remove the `if` statement comparing `reaction.emoji.name`.

Comment: So I tried this, and I've run into an issue. I want the bot to translate the translation (sentText) back to English, not the old text (text1) (because that just outputs the old text), because it can result in some funny translations. However, when I try to do that, this is the result. `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at replaceProjectIdToken (C:\Users\[Name]\node_modules\@google-cloud\projectify\build\src\index.js:31:23)`. Code is the same as example posted above with your changes, with text1 simply swapped out for sentText.

Comment: Seems to be related to the module you're using to translate. No idea how that's happening. Maybe ask a new question with the updated code?